Brother QL 800 label printer does not print the label even if I use the 32-bit b-pack SDK in C#
I have tried both b-pack SDKs (32-bit and 64-bit) in c# WPF application. but nothing works. the application put the label in the print queue for the printer but does not print the label. I have tried even the sample applications those come with the brother b-pack SDK. but printing is not working. When we print something using another software, it prints the labels. but only my application does not print the label. Here is the code I have tested last time. If anyone can help, Thank you very much.
Anyhow I need to print a label with the dynamic content. Is there any way to print without the b-pack SDK, I am happy to get to know about it.
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace QL_800_Printer_test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            
        }

        void HandlePrinted(int status, object value)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Printed event called");
        }


        private void print_label(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string strFilePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Brother bPAC3 SDK\\Templates\\nameplate1.lbx";

            bpac.PrinterClass printerClass = new bpac.PrinterClass();
            object[] printers = (object[])printerClass.GetInstalledPrinters();

            Trace.WriteLine("Installed printers: " + printers[0]);

            if (printerClass.IsPrinterOnline((string)printers[0]))
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Printer is online");
            }
            else
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Printer is offline");
            }

            bpac.DocumentClass doc = new bpac.DocumentClass();

            doc.Printed += new bpac.IPrintEvents_PrintedEventHandler(HandlePrinted);


            doc.SetPrinter((string)printers[0], false);

            // Print setting start
            doc.StartPrint("", bpac.PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault);

            // Open template
            doc.Open(strFilePath);

            // Adds a print job (2 jobs are printed)
            doc.PrintOut(1, bpac.PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault);

            // Print setting end (=Print start)
            doc.EndPrint();

            // Close template
            doc.Close();

        }
    }
}


The application and printer driver has to be compatible.  Often printers have a EPS and PCL driver and your data may be one format and the driver the other format.  The working application the software and the driver are using the same format.  You can have two drivers for same printer install on a machine (with different names) to allow both formats to work.

The printer uses PCL driver. I am using .lbx label file created in P-touch Editor provided by brother. I have another application that prints a label file which also has the .lbx file extension. that application uses something like this
instead of this line in my source code
**
bpac.DocumentClass doc = new bpac.DocumentClass()
**
that application uses this line
**
Document document = (Document) Activator.CreateInstance(Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("a_GUID_here")));
**
with that line that application successfully prints the label. could explain me why?

The printer settings are coming from the GUID.  Is your file PCL or EPS?  Did you try an EPS driver?  It may also be something like the font that is missing.

I think it is a PCL file because, I use it for small labels. But my application is also run in the same PC as the other application does. also, the working application folder does not even contain any font file. that means it uses a font file in the PC. If I use the same GUID as the other application does, can it work?

Not sure, try and see.

Ok, I'll check it. Thanks for your help!

Try putting the doc.open(strFilePath) before doc.startprint("", bpac.PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault) command. As with any file you need to open it before you can print it.

Thanks for your answer. Appreciate it. I found the error. I was not adding dependencies correctly. There is a video on youtube provided by brothers, how to use the SDK. The way I add the SDK is not the same as they do. Thank you!
